# UILabel with mutiple lines to truncate one long word

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `UIlabel` view which allow to show two lines of strings. But in my case, there is one long word only. Whatever I set the line break mode to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` or `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`, it always break the word into two lines. Like this:
"xxxxxx
xx"
I would like to truncate it in the first line, like this:
"xxxx..."

Is there any way to implement that. 
In most of the cases, it should allow to show two lines of words.

Additional edit:
Take following image as an example. The top two labels are what I expected: one long word can be truncated in one line; multiple short words can be show in two lines. 
The bottom label is currently happened.

[image]

Comment: I said, in some other cases, it should allow to show two lines(multiple short words can be shown in two lines). Just some rare cases, a long word would be character wrap into two lines, which I want to just show in one line with "...".

Comment: what you want exactly i did not get your point yet ?

Comment: I want to show text as top two images. It can show mutiple words in two lines as top right image, and can also show one long word in one line as top left image. I don't want the bottom image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to do what you're asking you need to find out if there is only one word. If there is, set the number of lines to 1 and the auto-shrink should fix things. If there is not, then set the number of lines to 0.

e.g.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8;
label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Information", @"E: 'Information'");
NSUInteger words = [label.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].count;
label.numberOfLines = (words == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

Swift 3.0

```
let label = UILabel()
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8
label.text = NSLocalizedString("Information", comment: "E: 'Information'")
let words = label.text?.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).count
label.numberOfLines = words == 1 ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont do anything

set number of line 1
no break mode

set font size and min font size same

see the image[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but not fit my case. Please see my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Set the number of line is one or don't set the number of lines by default is 1. And line break mode would be UILineBreakModeTailTruncation... and specially check the width of your label.... It should not be bigger use as following ...

```
  [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake:(10,10,50,30)];
  [lbl setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
  [lbl setNumberOfLines:1];
```

May this will help you ...

Comment: Thank you for answering, but not fit my case. Please see my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

By making the label more wider you can solve this issue.

```
[lbl setFrame:CGRectMake:(xPosition,yPosition,heightValue,21)];
```

`[lbl setNumberOfLines:1];`

where

> xPosition & yPosition values are values that you set for your label.
>
> heightValue is the appropriate value which will align your label in the view properly.

go on...

Comment: Thank you for answering, but not fit my case. Please see my above comment.